# SQL - Decimal out of range

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tenho uma tabela que representa produtos no estoque, ela possui um campo de quantidade `DECIMAL(5,3)`, eu entendi que são 5 dígitos antes da vírgula e 3 depois da vírgula, até 2 casas decimais antes da vírgula é inserido/atualizado na tabela normalmente, porém a partir de 3 casas decimais antes da virgula começa a emitir um erro "out of range", como eu posso armazenar um numero decimal com mais de 5 dígitos antes da vírgula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DECIMAL(5,3)` significa que o tamanho máximo são 5, sendo 3 digitos decimais, ou seja, o valor máximo é `99.999`.

Se precisar de 5 digitos e mais 3 decimais, então precisa de 8 digitos: `DECIMAL(8,3)`

Veja a documentação do `mysql`: [DECIMAL Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)